# Angular select tag with options and object comparison

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to set up a `<select>` tag with a pre-selected value. Unfortunately, I can't use the `ng-options` directive because the [ui-select2 module](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2) doesn't support it.

Here's an example (or, [as a Plunker if you would prefer](http://plnkr.co/edit/A0TSvgaGGaJeOSGKfuyG?p=preview)):

```
// Controller
$scope.colors = [{
  name: 'blue',
}, {
  name: 'red',
}, {
  name: 'green'
}];

$scope.selectedColor = $scope.colors[0];


<!-- HTML -->
<select ng-model="selectedColor">
  <option ng-repeat="color in colors" value="{{color}}">{{color.name}}</option>
</select>
```

In this instance I would expect angular to realise that `$scope.selectedColor` is the same object as the first color object and preselect correctly but it doesn't appear to work.

I can solve this problem by using `ng-options` or by comparing by name but neither of these solutions are ideal.

How can I correctly compare objects in Angular selects?

Answer (score 0):

I found an example online which seemed to use `ng-options` with `ui-select2` and it seems to work fine with what you require. See [Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/SMl4oeVKdnNIPAkJQ4Ub?p=preview).

HTML

```
<select ui-select2
    ng-model="selectedColor"
    ng-options="color.name for color in colors">
</select>
```

Controller

```
$scope.colors = [
{
    name: 'blue',
},
{
    name: 'red',
},
{
    name: 'green'
}];

$scope.selectedColor = $scope.colors[1];
```